# Magenta multistyle pastiche generator only generates solid black images?

Tags: python, machine-learning, tensorflow, magenta

I've been playing around with the Magenta Multistyle Pastiche Generator, but so far it will only generate solid black images. Someone on a GitHub forum had the same problem, and apparently Magenta is only compatible on CPU with TensorFlow 1.0.1? However, I installed 1.0.1 and I'm still having the same problem. Here's what I'm running in the terminal (after "source activate magenta", of course)

$ image_stylization_transform \

```
     --num_styles=10 \
     --checkpoint=/Users/NMB1331/Desktop/multistyle-pastiche-generator-monet.ckpt \
     --input_image=/Users/NMB1331/Desktop/test_image.jpg \
     --which_styles="{0:0.1,1:0.1,2:0.1,3:0.1,4:0.1,5:0.1,6:0.1,7:0.1,8:0.1,9:0.1}" \
     --output_dir=/Users/NMB1331/Desktop/PracticeOutput \
     --output_basename="all_monet_styles2"
```

Can anyone help me out, or perhaps direct me to somewhere where I can fix this problem? I've also tried upgrading magenta and tensorflow to the latest versions, but to no avail. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed environment by `docker` instead of `pip install magenta`, solved this problem.
https://github.com/tensorflow/magenta-demos/pull/18#issuecomment-334453199

Hoping that the information will be of some help to you.